# ¿Extracción de frases en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

En R ¿Cuál es la función que me permita buscar una palabra determinada y que me traiga la palabra que viene después de esa palabra? por ejemplo, se tiene:

Marca:  Avon
Marca:  Imusa
Marca:  Falabella ....etc.

Requiero que cada que encuentre la palabra "Marca", me traiga, "Avon", "Imusa", "Falabella", etc.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Traduciendo literalmente tu pregunta, una forma de hacerlo es así:

```
buscar_marca <- function(s, p=1) {
    # Devuelve la marca y la posición dónde se ubicó en el string
    key <- "Marca: "
    lkey <- nchar(key)
    s <- substr(s, p, nchar(s))
    pos = regexpr(key, s)

    s2 <- substr(s, pos+lkey, nchar(s))
    nextpos = regexpr(key, s2)

    if(nextpos == -1){nextpos = nchar(s2) + 1}
    marca <- substr(s2, 1, nextpos-1)

    return(c(trimws(marca),p+pos+lkey-1))
}
```

Entonces podemos hacer esto:

```
s <- 'Marca: Avon Marca: Imusa Marca: Falabella'
buscar_marca(s,1)  # "Avon" "8"
buscar_marca(s,8)  # "Imusa" "20"  
buscar_marca(s,20) # "Falabella" "33"
```

Lógicamente es para ir haciendo una búsqueda secuencial, sin embargo, para lo que entiendo que estas queriendo hacer, esto es mucho más óptimo, terminás con un vector de las marcas extraídas del string.

```
s <- 'Marca: Avon Marca: Imusa Marca: Falabella'
result<-sapply(strsplit(s, 'Marca: '), function(e) {trimws(e[e!=""])})  
result
[1,] "Avon"     
[2,] "Imusa"    
[3,] "Falabella"
```

Answer (score 1):

una alternativa es usando la librería `stringr` que es más literal en el uso:

Cargamos la librería y definimos el string de prueba

```
library(stringr)
string <- "Marca: Avon Marca: Imusa Marca: Falabella"
```

Extraemos todo lo que sea `"Marca: ALGO"` usando la función `str_extract_all`

```
marcas <- str_extract_all(string, "Marca: [A-Za-z]+")
marcas <- unlist(marcas)
marcas
#> [1] "Marca: Avon"      "Marca: Imusa"     "Marca: Falabella"
```

Luego limpiamos removiendo el string `"Marca: "` con la función `str_replace_all`

```
marcas <- str_replace_all(marcas, "Marca: ", "")
marcas
#> [1] "Avon"      "Imusa"     "Falabella"
```